# DateTime in if()

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datagrid

I need set color my row in `datagrid`, I use `loadingrow` event:

```
DataRowView item = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
if (item != null)
{
    DataRow row = item.Row;
    var colValue = row[3];
    if (colValue > DATETIME_NOW-10_MINUTES)
    {
        e.Row.Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FCD2CD");
    }
}
```

`colValue` is of type `datetime` is sql table.
How to set color row for last ten minutes?

Comment: Voted to close as Too Localized. [MSDN contains many answers to "does this exist" questions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods)

Comment: @sixlettervariables as I read the question again, I think the question is really "How do I write a condition for `> DATETIME_NOW-10_MINUTES` in c#?"

Comment: Note that the code with `Datetime.Now` checks "10 minutes from event time", not "10 minutes from query time" (which might be your preference).

Comment: @lc: That's how I read it from the start. Users of the .Net framework should start their search for answers at MSDN, viewing the Properties/Methods/Events on the data types in question and reviewing any examples, remarks, etc.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Well it took me a few tries to understand, so I guess you're a step ahead of me. :) Either way, I think I do agree with you on the too localized bit and certainly to start at MSDN and learn about `DateTime`. However, I did a quick search and I don't see an duplicate asking how to use negative values in `DateTime.Add*` so it *may* be worth keeping this one here, no matter how simple it may be.

Answer (score 4):

You have to cast the value from the Row and use some method of the `DateTime` structure like (`AddMinutes`, `AddHours`, `AddDays` as you need) and add a *negative* value to get a `DateTime` on the past. Take a look:

```
if (item != null)
{
    DataRow row = item.Row;
    var colValue = (DateTime)row[3];
    if (colValue > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10))
    {
        e.Row.Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FCD2CD");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(colValue > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10))
{
  e.Row.Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FCD2CD");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use DateTime.Now to get the current date/time and AddMinutes() to add some minutes (you can pass a negative value)

```
colValue > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a [custom value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that converts a date/time to a color. This way you can declarative bind the color to a field in your model and viceversa.

This is more the WPF way than doing it imperative in a code behind.

Comment: I think you have a point here. I missed the WPF tag completely.